# Form-based authentication programmatically log my users in

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, authentication

I am very new to SharePoint and very desperate for help.

I've implemented a custom login page along with forms authentication. This works fine, but I need to go one step further now. When the user hits the login page, i need to log them in automatically from the code if they are a domain user.

I've googled my fingers to stumps, but no solution i've found gives the code example I need. This is what I currently have:

```
Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("Domainusername", False)
Response.Redirect("http://sharepointdev/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx")

Dim Membership As CustomMembershipRolesProvider.CustomFBA.MembershipAndRoles.CustomMembershipProvider = New     CustomMembershipRolesProvider.CustomFBA.MembershipAndRoles.CustomMembershipProvider()
Membership.GetUser("Domainusername", False)
```

If this is utter nonsense, please give me a shout. Any and all help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using Windows Auth and NTLM?

Comment: apologies for the later reply, got a bit sidetracked. We will have users accessing the site that do not have domain accounts, outside of the business from their own personal pc's. As far as I know, this means Windows Auth won't work

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, for anyone that has this question as well, the following lines logs the user in via code-behind. Provided that you have done the setup for you custom membership provider correctly.

```
 SPIisSettings iisSettings;

if (iisSettings == null)
  {
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
       //gets the iis settings for you current site collection
       iisSettings = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(SPContext.Current.Site.Zone);
     });
   }
 //create an instance of the forms authentication provider used by SharePoint
 SPFormsAuthenticationProvider formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider =iisSettings.FormsClaimsAuthenticationProvider;

 //using the forms authentication instance created above, request the login from SharePoint in the form of a security token. 
 SecurityToken token = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url), formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider.MembershipProvider, formsClaimsAuthenticationProvider.RoleProvider, username, password, SPFormsAuthenticationOption.PersistentSignInRequest);

                //if the login request was successfull, you will have a valid token
                if (null != token)
                {
                //open a new session with the acquired token and redirect to which ever page is your landing page for your site collection. 
                    EstablishSessionWithToken(token);
                    base.RedirectToSuccessUrl();
                }
```

I hope this helps someone in the future, if it's a bit unclear, welcome to SharePoint, nothing is ever clear.